# Numpy 'where' on string

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I would like to use the numpy.where function on a string array. However, I am unsuccessful in doing so. Can someone please help me figure this out?

For example, when I use `numpy.where` on the following example I get an error:

```
import numpy as np

A = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']

arr_index = np.where(A == 'apple',1,0)
```

I get the following:

```
>>> arr_index
array(0)
>>> print A[arr_index]
>>> apple
```

However, I would like to know the indices in the string array, `A` where the string `'apple'` matches. In the above string this happens at 0 and 2. However, the `np.where` only returns 0 and not 2.

So, how do I make `numpy.where` work on strings? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
print(a[arr_index])
```

not `array_index`!!

```
a = np.array(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'])

arr_index = np.where(a == 'apple')

print(arr_index)

print(a[arr_index])
```

Comment: Thanks for the superfast reply! Ah, that is correct. Yes, but what I want are the indices where the string 'apple' matches in the string array. So, I want something like: 

arr_index = [0,2]   # that is 'apple' occurs are positions 0 and 2 in the string array a. However, it only gives me 0.

Comment: I just corrected the error in my post so that the main question is highlighted and not the stupid error. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe an easier way is to just do :

```
A = np.array(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'])
arr_index = np.where(A == 'apple')
print(arr_index)
```

And you get:

```
(array([0, 2]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that you need to use an array instead of a list to use where properly (also, use True and False instead of 1 and 0 to get a mask to look for the indexes):

```
A = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']
arr_mask = np.where(np.array(A) == 'apple',True,False)
arr_index = np.arange(0, len(A))[arr_mask]
```

This way, you'll get arr_index as:
np.array([0,2])

Notice that to use the mask arr_mask or the indexes arr_index to look for the values in A, A needs to be an array:

```
In [55]: A = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'] 
    ...: arr_mask = np.where(np.array(A) == 'apple',True,False) 
    ...: arr_index = np.arange(0, len(A))[arr_mask]                                                             

In [56]: A[arr_mask]                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-f8b153319425> in <module>
----> 1 A[arr_mask]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [57]: A[arr_index]                                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-91c260fe71ab> in <module>
----> 1 A[arr_index]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [58]: B = np.array(A)                                                                                        

In [59]: B[arr_mask]                                                                                            
Out[59]: array(['apple', 'apple'], dtype='<U6')

In [60]: B[arr_index]                                                                                           
Out[60]: array(['apple', 'apple'], dtype='<U6')
```

What you are getting using just the list is that the function np.where() doesn't find anywhere where the condition is satisfied. If you try:

```
A = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']
arr_index = np.where(A == 'orange',1,0)
```

You'll get again array(0) as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
def GetIndexOfStr(npArray,theStr): 
    #npArray is from type of numpy.ndarray where each item is of type np.str
    return np.where(npArray == theStr)[0][0]

A = np.array(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'])
print(A[GetIndexOfStr(A,"apple")]) # ==> this will result in "apple"
print(A[GetIndexOfStr(A,"appleX")]) # ==> this will throw IndexError
```