# Find a word in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x

```
word2 = "find"
np.where(dictionary == word2)[0]
```

The dictionary variable is a numpy array with thousands of words in the english dictionary, when looking for the index of a word, numpy also returns the index of all the strings containing word2 as a substring.

Does anyone has an idea of how to fix this? I would like to return just the perfect string match

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array(['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana'])

arr_index = np.where(a == 'apple')

print arr_index

print a[arr_index]
```

Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642022/numpy-where-on-string)